# Kerberos: Running an app with a parameter using krenew

Tags: linux, bash, kerberos

I need to run an application with `krenew`, but the application also needs to receive a parameter via command line and I need to send its output to a file. From [the documentation](http://www.eyrie.org/~eagle/software/kstart/krenew.html), it looks like this should do the trick:

`krenew -t -- sh -c 'compute-job > /afs/local/data/output'`

but, unfortunately, when I run the command below:

`krenew -s -- sh -c './my_app config.xml > results/test.txt &'`

the application just dies after a while and I can see from the output of `ps aux` that `krenew` is not running along with `my_app`. I am not sure what the parameter `-t` does, and as far as I can see, if I run `krenew -s ./my_app`, it works properly.

I hope someone can clarify this.

Update: If I remove the "&" character from the command (so it won't be  detached from the console it works just fine, so I decided to run it in a *SCREEN* tab. While this is not the best solution, it does the job.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of running it in a screen session you should be able to use:

```
krenew -t -- sh -c './my_app config.xml > results/test.txt' &
```

Notice the `&` detaching `krenew` from your shell, but not your application from the spawned `sh`. The `-t` parameter fetches a AFS token along with your Kerberos ticket. You only need this if your command needs to access a AFS file system.

Comment: That is cool. It would have never crossed my mind that `&` needs to be applied to `krenew` instead of the process that I want to run...